# SQL equality/inequality comparison with nullable values

Tags: sql, postgresql, comparison, equality

first take, kludge solution, sentinel approach(it's imperative that your program should not allow inputting of sentinel value):

```
 select coalesce(a, -2147483648) = coalesce(b, -2147483648) as is_equal -- a little postgresism
```

let's say you forgot to block the sentinel value on your program, the user inputted -2147483648 on the B field, and A is null.  the code above reports true, should report false, should not report true nor null.

what's the most concise way to compare equality on nullable fields? A == B should just report either true or false only, regardless if the field(s) are nullable or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably [IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) will help here.

Answer (score 0):

The operator <=> does what you want in other database engines; is it not in postgres? Otherwise, `a is null and b is null or (a is not null and b is not null and a == b)` should work. This works because `FALSE AND NULL` is `FALSE`.

Comment: doesn't work on postgresql(or other rdbms for that matter).  lucky mysql bastards for that operator :-p  anyway, +1 just in case some mysqlers chance upon this problem

Comment: At least with Oracle, the usual operators do NOT work as expected with null values...